# .Net Core JWT API implementation at Client Side

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am new to the .Net Core, and I am facing the following issues.

I have Authentication_API that returns ***JWT Token*** to the login controller at client side.
After successful login, I want to redirect to Home page, but when I use [Authorize] attribute to the controller it is not working, but without [Authorize] attribute it is displaying the home page.

Please help me how to solve this issue.
I think I am not saving the token in the header.

I was referencing the below API for JWT 
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/01/08/aspnet-core-22-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api

Here is my token generator

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
                    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                    {
                        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                        {
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserId.ToString()),
                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,user.Role.RoleNameE.ToString())
                        }),
                        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                    };
                    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                    var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

After this point, I want to redirect to Home page

this is my Startup page

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);


            // Add ASPNETCore DBContext services.
            services.AddDbContext<Tejoury_MSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));

            // configure strongly typed settings objects : abdulla
            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            //--------------- configure jwt(JSON Web Tokens) authentication : abdulla --------------- 
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                        var userId = int.Parse(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                        var user = userService.GetById(userId);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            // return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                            context.Fail("Unauthorized");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------

            // configure DI for application services : Abdulla
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole",
                    authBuilder =>
                    { authBuilder.RequireRole("Admin"); });

            });

        }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducibile Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you. In this case, post an extract of your code containing at least Startup.cs

Comment: @Pier I updated the quest..Please check ..thanks